# if else construction

Tags: if-statement, scheme

I am trying to solve a basic function. but I get an error with my second if statement  and the else.Ff you can give me a help here is the code.

```
(define (equation x)
  (if(> x 2) (+(-(* x x) x) 4) ) 
  (if (and (> x 1 ) (= x 1))  (and (< x 2) (= x 2)) (/ 1 x))
  (else 0)
  )
```

Comment: I don't know scheme but could it be you meant `or`s instead of `and`s?

Comment: no because both condition need to be true i think in the way it is now it only checks the first part of the second if

Comment: x can't be bigger AND equal to 1 but bigger OR equal to 1..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. And you should use a `cond` when dealing with multiple conditions (think of it as a series of IF/ELSE IF/.../ELSE statements).

Be aware that the expression `(and (> x 1) (= x 1))` will *never* be true, as `x` is either greater than or equal to `1`, both conditions can *never* be true at the same time. You probably meant `(or (> x 1) (= x 1))`, but even so that expression can be written more concisely as `(>= x 1)`. The same considerations apply for the condition `(and (< x 2) (= x 2))`.

I believe this is what you were aiming for:

```
(define (equation x)
  (cond ((> x 2)
         (+ (- (* x x) x) 4))
        ((and (>= x 1) (<= x 2))
         (/ 1 x))
        (else 0)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The format of if condition is `(if (condition) (consequent) (alternate))`. The `else` cannot be used with `if`. Here's the same code without using cond/else

```
(define (equation x)
  (if (> x 2) 
      (+ (- (* x x) x) 4)
      (if (and (or (> x 1) (= x 1)) (or (< x 2) (= x 2)))
          (/ 1 x)
          0)))
```

Or alternatively

```
(define (equation2 x)
  (if (< x 1) 
      0
      (if (> x 2)
          (+ (- (* x x) x) 4)
          (/ 1 x))))
```

Answer (score 1):

and (> x 1 ) (= x 1) is alwayse false

and (< x 2) (= x 2) is always false

There is no operator to connect work with the second if

Comment: so if i want 1<=x<=2 how can i represent it in scheme

Comment: I dont know sheme, but I think it is something like prefix notation. and (> x 0) (< x 3) for example .... edit: works only with integers

Comment: @Doesn't Matter: I posted that answer 3 minutes ago